# Is there a way to get params from a XMLHttpRequest response?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Say I'm interested in checking the params that were sent with the XMLHttpRequest.

For instance, if I sent a POST petition with param 'option=1' can I retrieve that from the response?

I checked for the methods and properties but haven't seen a way to get it.

Comment: No, the response is the response and not the request. You should however be able to trivially remember the parameters you sent and pass them to your checker along with the response.

Comment: you need to provide more context: XMLHttpRequest is on client side, what do you use to receive the request on the server side? and by the way, you going to need to check the parameters from the request not the response.

Comment: The point was to get the parameters that were sent in the request without having to store them in variables.

Thanks for the replies anyway though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bergi said it's not possible to retrieve the parameters that were sent with the request on the response. So I'm closing the question.

Thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Fire a `XMLHTTPRequest` and examine the response object in your browser's JS console (F12 for Chrome/Firefox).

I believe the data is not there, at least I once changed the `XMLHttpRequest` `open()` method for a project (of course, I might have been just too stupid to find it). That way, my default error handler knows the original URL when printing errors to the user/sending errors to the error reporting backend.

Rough code snippet, pulled from a projects init-code:

```
/**  
 * Check XMLHttpRequest availability
 */
var ajax = null;
var proto = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest ();
    proto = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    try {
        ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
        proto = ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0").prototype;
    } catch (e) { }
}    

if (ajax == null) {
    alert ("Can not create AJAX object. You need a more recent browser!");
    return;
}    

/**  
 * Update ajax prototype to store the URL (for better error handling)
 */
try {
    var origOpen = proto.open;
    proto.open = function (method, url) {
        this._url = url; 
        return origOpen.apply (this, arguments);
    }    
} catch (e) {
    console.log ("Can not patch XMLHttpRequest to store URL. Console output will omit them...");
}
```

You would need to adapt this for POST data passed to the `send()` function instead. **Be aware, that the method is probably bad style, and my JS style might be even worse!**

**Better**: But you could always pass the POST data directly to the callback function, without storing it in the XMLHTTPRequest object:

```
var postData = "SomeStuff-Foobar123";
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest (); //add magic for other browsers here
ajax.open ("POST", "ajax.php", true);
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState != 4 || this.status != 200) {
        console.log ("Not ready, yet...");
        return 0;
    }
    //response is in this.responseText
    //but you can still access the parent objects!
    console.log ("Done with Code 200. POSTed data: " + postData);
}
ajax.send (postData);
```